# classloader class.forName can load all the classes inside one package using .*

Tags: java, jar, classloader

Thanks for helping me out

Today I have a very simple problem

***Problem:***

On my application startup, I am loading all the classes inside one package using

```
Class.forName("org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerator$Feature");
............................
............................ and so on
```

Like this I loaded all the classes, everything is fine, until I upgrade the Jar, so the Jar package is updated to some other package name, from `org.codehaus.jackson` to `com.fasterxml.jackson`. So I have to change `class.forName` code.

***Solution required:***
Is the following code is possible

```
Class.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.*");
```

or there is any other way to load all the classes under one package?

please help :)

Comment: Putting these classes on the classpath isn't enough for you? This sounds really weird to me.

Comment: Yes I can add, this facility is available I know that I just want to know is there any other feasibility or not .

Comment: Your code above accomplishes exactly nothing useful, unless you have unused classes with static initializers or some other strange architecture. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Your problem stems from code duplication and can be solved with the usual approaches: `String pkg = "org.codehaus.jackson."; Class.forName(pkg+"JsonGenerator"); Class.forName(pkg+"JsonGenerator$Feature"); Class.forName(pkg+ ..and..so..on..);` Then, there's a single place where you have to change `"org.codehaus.jackson."` to `"com.fasterxml.jackson."`. This does not affect what others said, such preloading should not be needed.

Answer (score -1):

The `Class.forName("com.fasterxml.jackson.*");` is not possible,
[docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) are very clear about it, that the name parameter should be:

> name - fully qualified name of the desired class

In addition the `Class.forName` returns a single object representing a class behind given name.

Your question has that, if you upgrade/update jar file the packages of jackson can be one of `org.codehaus.jackson` or `com.fasterxml.jackson`. This is weird if you want to load the jackson classes dynamically and you are not sure what will be the base package for those classes.

But anyway, a kind of solution would be to scan with Reflections if the given package name contains required classes (or at least few of them, so you would know that the package is visible) like here:
[Can you find all classes in a package using reflection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520328/can-you-find-all-classes-in-a-package-using-reflection/22462785)
And later loop through the package with classes to initialize them with `Class.forName`.

Comment: This doesn't make any more sense than the question. Reflection can't see a class that hadn't been loaded yet, and if it has been loaded already there is nothing else that needs doing.